# Richfaces 4.x Calendar Component ondateselected event

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, calendar, richfaces

In one of my applications where I use RichFaces 4.0, I am using the calendar control. I would like to read the value of the selected date and use it in javascript (for instance alert the selected value to the user). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options via Richfaces JavaScript API . The following EL will return the value of the component of the supplied client id (`findComponent`) is an RF function

```
    #{rich:findComponent('input').value}
```

Or

```
     #{rich:component('input component').value}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an p:ajax request with

```
 onstart="alert('sometext'#yourbean.datevalue);"
```

Or you could add a `<p:dialog/>` and a `<p:ajax/>`. And display the dialog when your event is triggerd.